# Where can I find user identity when using webapi with Windows Authentication on IIS8

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, iis-8

I'm trying to find out how to find the identity of the logged on user in an webapi. On dev server and on older IIS7 the identity is available in multiple places, but when I try to set up my application on IIS8 all known sources are blank.

Using `<authentication mode="Windows" />` I can normally see the user identity in the following places:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
User.Identity.Name
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

But on IIS8 they all come up empty.

Any ideas where to look, or how to configure IIS8 or my application to find the useridentity ?

Comment: Have you enabled windows authentication on that server? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_burgs_blog/archive/2013/11/05/installing-adding-iis-windows-authentication-feature-in-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
ApiController.User
```

is what you need. Web API is free of System.Web so it behaves differently.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get the user in an http module, outside of a controller?

Answer (score 0):

You are authenticating with an anonymous user.
You can disallow anonymous access by editing the `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />   <!-- The question-mark represents the `anonymous`-user) -->
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Normally when `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` is empty the windows authentication failed. Take a look at `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated`.

**Compare the settings** between IIS7 and IIS8 too.
(app-pool, web.config and also the **IIS-Authentication settings**)

Another problem could be the client (Browser and its settings) you are using.
Maybe the browser does not deliver the windows identity.

For **Internet Explorer** verify:
`Settings -> Advanced -> "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication*"`